# Understanding what the sigma-field should be in dice-experiment

Tags: measure-theory

I'm new at measure theory and would like some guidance on how to solve this (probably very easy) task:

Throw a fair dice twice. We have the following information of a given outcome: "Two sixes";"Exactly one six"; "No sixes".
Describe the probability space ($\Omega$,$\mathcal{F}$,$\textbf{P}$) that corresponds to this information. 
Also give all $\mathcal{F}$-measurable functions
$X:\Omega\rightarrow\{-1,1,2,3,...\}$ med $E(X)=0$,
corresponding to a fair game.

My thoughts so far:

The sample space should contain all the "pairs" of dices, where the order is not relevant: $\Omega=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,4),(4,5),(4,6),(5,5),(5,6),(6,6)\}$
I'm having troubles to understand what the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$ should be. 
I thought that I should include all the three events described, but then it's not a $\sigma$-field. What am I doing wrong?
$\mathcal{F}=\{\{\emptyset\},\{(6,6)\},\{(6,1),...(6,6)\},\{(1,1),...,(5,5)\},\{\Omega\}\}$

Comment: In an experiment with only finitely many outcomes, it is normal to let $\cal F$ be the collection of **all** subsets of $\Omega$, i.e. $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are used to finite outcome spaces $\Omega$ where the outcomes are equiprobable.

This answer shows you that it can be done differently.

If I understand well then *only the number of sixes is involved*, and this number takes values in $\{0,1,2\}$.

Then it is actually enough to go for $\Omega=\{0,1,2\}$ equipped with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F=\wp(\Omega)$.

It remains to define the probability measure $\mathbf P:\wp(\Omega)\to\mathbb R$.

Based on the fact that the die is fair we find easily that:

- $\mathbf P(\{0\})=\frac56\frac56=\frac{25}{36}$
- $\mathbf P(\{2\})=\frac16\frac16=\frac{1}{36}$
- $\mathbf P(\{1\})=\frac56\frac16+\frac16\frac56=\frac{10}{36}$

This determines $\mathbf P$ completely for every event $A\in\mathcal F$ by:$$\mathbf P(A)=\sum_{a\in A}\mathbf P(\{a\})$$

Further *every* function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable (as is always the case if the chosen $\sigma$-algebra is the powerset of $\Omega$).

Advantage of the constructed probability space is that only relevant information is contained. More concise is not even possible.

Comment: So what does $\mathcal{F}$ look like in this case?
I mean, shouldn't it contain all the subsets of $\Omega$?  But then, what meaning does $\{0,2\}$ have in this case, how does that describe the probability space?

Comment: $\mathcal F$ is indeed the collection of all subsets of $\Omega$. Notation for that $\mathcal F=\wp(\Omega)$. Event $\{0,2\}$ "occurs" if the number of sixes that is thrown is an even number. What do you mean with: "how does that describe the probability space?"?

Comment: Ok, now I get it, I was thinking about it from the wrong angle.
I have one more question though. You wrote that every function is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable if the chosen $\sigma$-algebra is the powerset of $\Omega$). Lets say that we have $\Omega=\{0,1,2\}$ but we are only interested in the events of "two sixes" and "no sixes", does that mean that $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset,\Omega,\{0\},\{2\},\{0,2\}\}$ and that only functions X that takes values 0 or 2 are $\mathcal{F}$-measurable?

Comment: Focusing on only an even number of sixes does not affect the probability space. It can still be used, but then it contains some extra information. If you want to avoid that then it is possible to build a new one then with $\Omega=\{0,2\}$, $\mathcal F=\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{2\},\{0,2\}\}$, $\mathbf P(\{0\})=\frac{25}{26}$ and $\mathbf P(\{2\})=\frac{1}{26}$. Note that here $P(\{0\})+P(\{2\})=1$ (as it should) and note that the probabilities $P(\{0\})$ and $P(\{2\})$ have the same ratio as in the original space.